# Ways of Optimizing "Header" of Website by Sending POST Request Only Once

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies

Currently I have a website with multiple web pages, which contain the same header with information such as User Name, User Profile Pic, etc.

Now I want to display the User Name and User Profile Pic after they successfully log in. Therefore, I have to use PHP to retrieve the user information from the server. Considering that I have multiple web pages, I am wondering whether there is a way that, instead of retrieving the information every time the user enters a new page, can I get the information only once from the server and store it somewhere in the browser and use it afterwards? I am thinking of using the following ways:

1. Pass the user data by the parameters in the URL, but it is definitely insecure.
2. Use LocalStorage or SessionStorage, but it is not compatible in some older browsers.
3. Store it in the Cookie, but it will not be efficient if it contains lots of data, such as the user's profile pic.

Comment: Once a user gets logged in, you can store name, image name, etc ... in `$_SESSION` (that will be one query per successful user login), and if you are giving an option to update those details, you can change on successful edit, that is what sessions are meant for.

Comment: Don't store the information with the user (via cookies, etc) as the user can then change that information and pretend to be any other user

Answer (score 0):

As **Viral** has stated in the comments, you could utilise PHP's `$_SESSION` which will persist data across web pages providing you start the session on each web page using `session_start()`.

An example implementation of this could be as follows;

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['userdata']){
    //Get user data and store it within the session eg. $_SESSION['usedata'] = array('name' => 'Scott');

    //This will allow you to get the user data if it has not already been retrieved.
}

// Use the data however you would need to
```

I would suggest using sessions as they are supported in almost all browsers that support cookies.